# Hybris AddressReversePopulator does not populate Line1 on AddressModel

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm having issues using `AddressReversePopulator` for converting `AddressData` to `AddressModel`.

The problem shows up on this line on `populate(addressData, addressModel)` method

```
addressModel.setLine1(addressData.getLine1());
addressModel.setLine2(addressData.getLine2());
```

The method setLineX on `AddressModel.java` uses

```
getPersistenceContext().setDynamicValue(this,LINE1, value);
```

but the `DynamicAttributesProvider()` in the `ItemModelContextImpl.class` is null when triying to populate Line1 and Line2, therefore it does not fill the two values in `addressModel` but in the other fields of the populator this Provider is ok.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In This case if you are receiving Line1 and Line2 as null so try to set empty string and go ahead. it will work.
Sample example:

```
addressModel.setLine1(formatLine1(addressData.getLine1()));
private String formatLine1(String line1)
{
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(line1))
    {
        return "";
    }

    String[] parts = line1.split(",");
    if (parts.length > 0)
    {
        String[] newLine1 = Arrays.stream(parts).filter(p -> !p.isEmpty()).toArray(String[]::new);

        return String.join("," + " ", newLine1);
    }
    return "";
}
```